# Finite element welding simulation with commercial software?

Tags: structural-analysis, stresses, finite-element-method, simulation, welding

I am looking forward some libraries/add-ons to perform welding simulation (thermomechanical coupling, steel alloys) using commercial software, like Ansys or Abaqus. My aim is to determine better welding patterns that minimize residual stresses and/or distortion, in an industrial setting. As far as I know this issue has been addressed in the research literature (using complex heat source patterns, phase transformation material properties and birth/death of elements), but I have found very little to no reference in commercial software, and the company I work with cannot afford to fund a university-type research group.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: You won't find much reference to using commercial software in the research literature, because (rightly or wrongly) "creating and validating a model using commercial software" doesn't count as "academic research". (But "re-inventing a square wheel that is a poor imitation of the round wheels already available in commercial software" does count as "academic research." Try some engineering conference proceedings rather than academic journals.